# Trying to rewrite a deprecated jquery function fn.click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on updating jQuery for a really old wordpress site.  I have the function below that I'm trying to rewrite:

```js
$(".smscroll").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    //  CALCULATE DESTINATION PLACE
    var dest = 0;

    if ($(this.hash).offset().top > ($(document).height() - $(window).height()))
    {
        dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    }
    else
    {
        dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
    }

    //  GO TO DESTINATION
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000, 'swing');
});
```

I realize that `.click` is deprecated. So, I'm trying to replace it with the following:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".smscroll", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
  
    //  CALCULATE DESTINATION PLACE
    var dest = 0;
  
    if ($(this.hash).offset().top > ($(document).height() - $(window).height()))
    {
        dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    }
    else
    {
        dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
    }
  
    //  GO TO DESTINATION
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:dest}, 1000, 'swing');
  });
```

What else do i need to clean up to get rid of the deprecation?

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your code no longer contains deprecated functionality, although
`$(document).on('click', scope, callback)` is redundant. Use `$(scope).on('click', callback)` like so:

```js
$(".smscroll").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var dest = 0;
  if ($(this.hash).offset().top > ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
    dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
  } else {
    dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
  }
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: dest
  }, 1000, 'swing');
});
```

Assuming of course that the event listener is applied after all the `.smscroll` elements that need to ever be selected have been loaded. Of course, don't use this if your aim is to delegate the click event to the `.smscroll` class.

Comment: I would also add that, instead of using $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: dest
  }, 1000, 'swing'); you could just use the vanilla.js `scrollTo` which can be `smooth` now and will give better perf.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, https://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/ is really useful, replacements for deprecated functions etc are given there. In [this case](https://api.jquery.com/click-shorthand/):

- Instead of `.click( handler )` or `.click( eventData, handler )`, use `.on( "click", handler )` or `.on( "click", eventData, handler )`, respectively.
- Instead of `.click()`, use `.trigger( "click" )`.

Also a shoutout to [jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) together with the browser console log to clean up old jquery code in case you're not already aware of it.